# Full width text and references in margin using marginnotes

Tags: bibliographies, tufte

The tufte-book document class uses marginnotes to display references, and using the environment `fullwidth` allows sections of text to extend into the margin (the answer to my [previous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281499/how-is-this-layout-achieved) question gives an example of the latter). I'd use that document class were it not for the fact that using the packages amsmath and musixtex simultaneously results in an error - even the following produces errors when compiling:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Note: I have all the prerequisite packages necessary for tufte-latex.

So I'd like to replicate those features without using tufte-book. Is this feasible, and if so, how would I go about doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stole some code from ceasar-book and fixed it for book.cls.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\overhang}
\setlength{\overhang}{\marginparwidth}
\addtolength{\overhang}{\marginparsep}
%
\newenvironment{fullwidth}
  {\if@twoside\begin{adjustwidth*}{}{-\overhang}%
      \else\begin{adjustwidth}{}{-\overhang}%
      \fi
  }%
  {\if@twoside\end{adjustwidth*}%
     \else\end{adjustwidth}%
     \fi
  }

\begin{document}

\begin{fullwidth}
left \hfill right
\end{fullwidth}
\end{document}
```